# XmlAttributes.XmlIgnore Equivalent for XAML

Tags: .net, vb.net, xaml, serialization

How do I tell the xaml serilization to ignore a property.  IE the equivalent of the XmlAttributes.XmlIgnore attribute for xml serialization.

```
Class MyObject

   'Is there an equivalent of this for xaml?
   <XmlIgnoreAttribute()> Public Property DontSerializeMe as String

End Class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Attribute XmlIgnore and XamlWriter class - XmlIgnore not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575555/c-attribute-xmlignore-and-xamlwriter-class-xmlignore-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```