# Serialize WPF Image Control but ignore Source property in runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

I'm currently working on an editor like WPF application where you can choose to edit a control and then a dialog opens with a copy of the control in it. For the copying of the control I use the `XamlReader.Parse(string)` and `XamlWriter.Save(obj)`.

Now there are some (custom) controls than contain an Image control who has their `Source` set to an `WriteableBitmap`. The Bitmap is not serializable so the serializer is throwing some exceptions, but that's not the main problem because it isn't required to be serialized because it gets changed later anyways.

Is there a way to Serialize a **WPF-Control** and tell the Serializer to **ignore a property** of its children or override it with something that is serializeable (like *null*) **in runtime**?

I've already tried to manually set the source Property before and after serialization but for some unkown reason I can't change the Source of the deserialized control.

**Code for the dialog**

```
public void LaunchEditor()
{
    Editor dlg = new Editor ();
    dlg.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    dlg.SetTemplateString(XamlWriter.Save(this));
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() ?? false)
    {
        string s = dlg.GetTemplateString();
        CustomControlType c = (CustomControlType)XamlReader.Parse(s);
        Content = c;
    }
}
```

**Code for serialization**

```
public void SetTemplateString(string template)
{
    Placeholder = (CustomControlType)XamlReader.Parse(template);

    /*Formatting Stuff*/
}

public string GetTemplateString()
{           
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
    {
        Indent = true
    };
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb,settings);
    XamlDesignerSerializationManager mgr = new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(writer);
    XamlWriter.Save(Placeholder, mgr);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**Custom control that contains the Image**

```
public partial class RollingViewControl : ContentConstrol
{
    private RollingBitmap _bmp;
    public RollingViewControl()
    {
        _bmp = new RollingBitmap(256, 256);
        InitializeComponent();
        ImageDisplay.Source = _bmp.Bitmap;
    }
}
```

`RollingBitmap` is a Class for Manupilating the `WriteableBitmap` who is a Property of this Class.

The problem is the Source property of the Image Control, when serializing the Control the Source also gets serialized. Because it is precompiled code I cannot set any Attributes and I haven't found any way to apply `XmlAttributeOverrides` to the `XamlWriter`.

Comment: Only Public properties get serialized so you can make the image private.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [C# Attribute XmlIgnore and XamlWriter class - XmlIgnore not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4575555/3744182).  Agree?

Comment: The Problem is the Source property of the Image Control, when serializing the Control the Source also gets serialized. Because its precompiled code I cant set any Attributes and I haven't found any way to apply Attributeoverrides to the XamlWriter.

Comment: Hi, i have the sam problem. Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: I ended up writing a Placeholder Class for the WPF Control with the Properties I needed. Then the Placeholder gets serialized and deserialized. All that is left to to is write some functions for moving the data between the two classes.